# Flask Log In Validation + Possible Documentation Error

Tags: python, validation, authentication, documentation, flask

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/64/

I was reading the Flask docs.

I was just wondering if there is an error in the docs or maybe there's something I don't understand.

Shouldn't "if form.validate_on_submit():" be "if form.validate()"?

If not, how is the validate method used in the instance?

Thank you very, very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://packages.python.org/Flask-WTF/#flask.ext.wtf.Form.validate_on_submit):

> #### `validate_on_submit()`
>
> Checks if form has been submitted and if so runs validate. This is a
>   shortcut, equivalent to `form.is_submitted() and form.validate()`

Comment: Cool. There are always more and more docs to read eh! Can't catch them all, can you (well unless your Ash #pokemon)!

Good job, by the way, Blender.

Comment: Yeah, Flask and its extensions are really well-documented and neatly organized. They're pretty neat.